# Add multiple access policy in Key Vault for different resource group object id

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add multiple access policy in key vault for 2 object ids. One of them which belongs  to same resource  group as key vault and another belongs to a different resource group.

```
"resources": [
{
    "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
    "apiVersion": "2021-11-01-preview",
    "name": "[parameters('vaultName')]",
    "location": "[resourcegroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "sku": {
            "family": "A",
            "name": "standard"
        },
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "accessPolicies": [
            {
                "tenantId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionName'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId]",
                "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionName'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
                "permissions": {
                    "secrets": [
                        "get",
                        "list"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "tenantId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionNameAnotherRg'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId]",
                "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionNameAnotherRg'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
                "permissions": {
                    "secrets": [
                        "get",
                        "list"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "enabledForDeployment": false,
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
        "enableSoftDelete": true,
        "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90
    }
}
]
```

I am getting error as application does not found in resource group. Can someone please help

Comment: KeyVault doesn't care about ResourceGroups, just tenants.  What is the actual error you're receiving?

Comment: @MattSmall This was the error message I was getting.

 ResourceNotFound: The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites/FunctionName' under resource group 'Resource-Group-Name' was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. We need to specify resource group name in order to grant access to another application belongs to another resource group.

```
{
"tenantId": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('AnotherResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('FunName')), '2021-03-01', 'Full').identity.tenantId]",
"objectId": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('AnotherResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('FunName')), '2021-03-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
"permissions": { "secrets": [ "Get", "list" ] }
}
```